# Is there any limitation on file names under Unix?

Tags: unix, crontab

We are using crontab to schedule jobs and it was not picking the files for processing that contain `[` or `]` or `¿`.

Is there any limitation on file names or do these characters mean something in UNIX?

Are there any other variables we shouldn't use in file names?

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457994/what-characters-should-be-restricted-from-a-unix-file-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix systems, file names can contain every character except for:

- `/` (a forward slash)
- `NUL` (ASCII null)

Apart from that, POSIX allows for any kind of character, even UTF-8 – but that does not mean that every application (be it a shell, command line tool, file system etc.) may handle it. For portability reasons you should use the [portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_278).

Just make sure that whenever you use characters with special shell meaning (such as `*` globs), you quote the filename, e.g. if your file is called `file*name`, use:

```
./some-command "file*name"
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on filesystem, eg. ext4 permits (from wikipedia)

> all bytes except NUL ('\0') and '/' and the special file names "." and
>   ".."